# In unix by using vstart command i connect to db. i want to see code behind vstart cmd?

Tags: shell, unix, progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

I am using Progress DB. From Unix we do vstart to connect to Progress DB. I want to know code behind this. How can I do that?

I dont know if that is a unix command or something user created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which vstart` will look for `vstart` in your active `PATH`.

If that doesn't work you will get a message:

```
/usr/bin/which: no vstart in (... your path here...)
```

If that is the case you can use `find` instead:

```
find / -name "vstart"
```

This will look for vstart in the root-directory and all directories above the root.

Otherwise you will see something like

```
/usr/local/script/vstart
```

Matching files will be displayed like matching files for which so follow the directions below.

Change directory to the listed directory: `cd /usr/local/script/` and `cat` or `more` the file:

Cat command:

```
cat vstart
```

More command:

```
more vstart
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try

```
which vstart
```

So you know where the program is. then

```
cd
```

to the directory it shows, and now we come to the real problem:
I never heard of vstart, so I'm guessing it's a script from your company. If so, just

```
cat vstart
```

to see the shell code behind it. Now, if it's not a shell, I'd guess you'd be out of luck. Progress is not open source, except for some parts of it that are distributed for customization.